# PHP: str_word_count count minus as a separate word

Tags: php, count

```
<?php
echo str_word_count(' - - - - - - - ');exit;
```

Count words is 7, but there are no words. How to make this function work fine?

Comment: Read da manual "For the purpose of this function, 'word' is defined as a locale dependent string containing alphabetic characters, which also may contain, but not start with "'" and "-" characters. "

Comment: @u_mulder If that's true, why does it return `7` for OP in their example? Surely each of those counts as "starting" with `-`, so they shouldn't be counted, right? Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: And that's really strange( Maybe "starts with" means "there are at least 2 symbols and first is not `-`".

Comment: Think the doc is written wrong. Looks like it is just start or end of string for those chars, https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/dd858460bb7ad230449fa9643e1206b74b6355de/ext/standard/string.c

Comment: From testing it appears that the "does not start with '-' " aspect of the manual is simply incorrect. A "word" is any set of numbers or letters and `-` or `_` except numerical only character groups.

Comment: This brings up some [interesting results](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1e09182087b32150ea96fc2e27db5054b4cb4585); it seems the first "character block" of the tested string is judged differently from the later blocks of the tested string.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, `str_word_count` can act quite strangely.

Here's one alternative way to compute the number of words, using a simple regex instead:

```
function count_words(string $string): int
{
  return preg_match_all('/\b(?:[^\W\d_]|-)+\b/u', $string, $matches) 
    ? count($matches[0]) 
    : 0;
}

echo count_words(' - - - - - - - '), PHP_EOL;  // 0
echo count_words('hello world'), PHP_EOL;      // 2
echo count_words('hoho hé-hé haha'), PHP_EOL;  // 3 
echo count_words('hello 123'), PHP_EOL;        // 1
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/18vq2)

This simply counts every occurrence of the string when a series of letters is found:

- `[^\W\d_]` basically represents any character you can find in a word except hyphens,
- the `u` flag ensures accented characters are taken into account.

Comment: With the example set by the OP, this function still returns 7.

Comment: @Martin Forgot word boundaries, shoud be fine now (altered the pattern multiple times and I broke that at some point, my bad).

Comment: It counts digits as words.

Comment: @Hevyweb Oops, that's right. Fixed the regex again.